# How to avoid nested async blocks in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's not a big problem, however, I find it sometimes quite "ugly" to write code as such:

```
angular.module('xxx', []).controller('xxxCtrl', function() {
  someAsyncCall(params, function callback(result) {
    //millions of lines here dependent on "result".
  }
})
```

I'm not using routing here so I cannot use "resolve".

Is there any other means to avoid that?

Comment: Is it possible to move some or all of the async call-related code into a service?

Comment: You'll probably want to use `$q` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: @NateBarbettini It's actually all $scope related in one of my recent cases, hence I do not think it's viable to move them into a service.

Comment: @PatrickGunderson Thanks for the tip. I actually did experiment with $q and angular.module('').run() but found it cannot delay the initialization of controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Extending Patrick's comment, using $q you could then do something like the following pattern:

```
/* handlers, parsers, ... */
function parseSomeAsyncResult() { ... }
...
function displaySomeAsyncResult() { ... }
function errorHandler() { ... }

/* now we can chain together as many handlers as needed to process our results */
someAsyncCall(params)
  .then(parseSomeAsyncResult)
  .then(displaySomeAsyncResult)
  .catch(errorHandler);
```

Comment: If I need to get 4 values asynchronously first, that would still be a little nasty without the help of async libraries like async. Obviously, I wouldn't like to include such libraries in my page in order to only achieve that. Is there any other tip?

Comment: To handle a list of promises you can use `$q.all()` which also gives you a promise  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all